# gcc undefined reference between libraries

Tags: gcc, linker, static-libraries, nm

At linking time, I'm getting the following:

```
libMain.a(Object.o): In function `Object': 
Object.cpp(44): undefined reference to `Transform::MakeIdentity()'
```

It is definitely seen from using `nm --defined-only libSystem.a`

```
Transform.o:
00000000 T Transform::MakeIdentity()
```

Both libSystem.a and libMain.a are being input appropriately. Linker command line options:

> -o "Game.so" -shared -Wl,-z,noexecstack "-lstdc++" "-lsupc++" "-lgnustl_static" "-lgcc" "libSystem.a" "libMain.a" -nostdlib -l"c" -l"m" -l"log" -l"gcc" -Wl,-soname,"libGame" -Wl,--no-undefined

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/linker-order-gcc

Comment: @NPE Just editted my question to mention I've tried re-ordering libraries.

Comment: Does it make a difference that your file is a `.cpp` but you're using gcc instead of g++?

Comment: @AustinMullins As far as I'm aware, gcc will invoke g++ on .cpp files.

Comment: @NPE Nevermind, that solved it - thanks. When I was putting them twice in the IDE I was using, it would delete the second mention of the same library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order in which you link static libraries matters. For a detailed discussion, see [Why does the order in which libraries are linked sometimes cause errors in GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/linker-order-gcc)